# Creating pointers to locations in an array

Tags: pointers, assembly, memory

I am a beginner with assembly, so please let me know if I forget important info. My assignment is about working with memory and I'm a bit confused on getting addresses from memory locations vs getting the values at said locations.

To be specific, I have an array of integers. I'd like to have a register pointing to the first item, and a register pointing to the last item. I'm given the pointer to the first item in register 0, r0, and the number of items as r1.

```
@ Given values:
@ r0 - pointer to first item in array
@ r1 - number of items in array

mov r3, r1          @ r3 = (r1)
lsl r3, #2          @ r3 = (r1*4)
sub r3, r3, #4      @ r3 = (r1*4)-4
add r3, r0, r3      @ r3 = r0+(r1*4-4)

ldr r2, [r3]        @ r2 points to last item
ldr r1, [r0]        @ r1 points to first item
```

Given these two, I could get the last item with (r0 + r1*4 - 4), correct? With that value, I'm trying to move the address of that last item into r2 below. Is this the proper way to get and store addresses, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your idea is correct, but you could simplify your code to just `mov r3, #-4; add r3, r3, r1 lsl #2`.

Comment: @fuz, you seem to be assuming a particular instruction set? He didn’t specify, and the instructions he’s using are pretty generic.

Comment: @prl It does look like ARM a lot, but OP should really specify an instruction set.  I have downvoted the question until OP edits it to specify an instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

Your first four statements correctly put the *address* of the last item in the array into r3.

Your last two statements load the *value* of the last item into r2 and the *value* of the first item into r1.